Unable to run "django-admin" after closing vs code
I am working on a website project and someone suggested I do a Django tutorial.  Using my VS Code, I ran through the steps to install using pip and then during the project I was instructed to setup a virtual environment.  I had ended part of the project and when I went go back to the tutorial, nothing is working.  I tried to run "django-admin" to review the available commands but I get error "django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet".  I go to check the version of Python and Django and I get similar error's regarding "not recognized".  I am able to run a python file but no command line commands.   I'm wondering if something go messed up regarding the "PATH".  I'm not an expert on any of these items, evidently just enough to make things break.
Please advise,

Did you reactivite the virtual environment where you installed Django?

I did not, I'll see how that is done.  I am not planning on having multiple virtual environments.  Only one version of each app.  I do plan on using the new project functionality in Django.

It seems there's an issue related to the PATH env variable.
You should add python and django to the system path variable to run python and django commands.
Adding system variables vary according to the OS you are using.
Let me assume you are using Windows.
if the command python --version doesn't work and have an error, it indicates python is not added to the system path.
Right click on This PC in the explorer and select Properties.
Click on "Advanced system settings" on the left or right(it might vary).
Click on the "Environment Variables" button.
In the "System variables" section, find the "Path" variable and select it, Click "Edit".
Click "New" and add the path to your Python installation.(e.g., C:\Python39\ and C:\Python39\Scripts).
Click ok to save the changes.
After doing this, you should activate your virtual environment and you could use python commands like pip install djanog or somehting.

I did a search for python and found this with the ".exe"
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
just add this path

I added the whole path to the Environment variable and when I check the version of Python - NameError: name 'python' is not defined.  Wonder if I have to uninstall/reinstall everything?

You should add AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312 and AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts to the path.
Let me know if it worked.

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts
Add this to the path. Here, admin is the username so you should change it.

Perfect!!!!!  I needed to add the scripts as well.  I restarted vscode and then install django again and it is working!  Thanks
